# Processing a PDF with embedded image using Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, prawn

I'm trying to process a PDF with Ghostscript 9.05 that contains an image.  The original PDF displays fine in Adobe Acrobat Reader 9 as well as Ubuntu's built in Document Viewer.

When running the file through Ghostscript I get:

```
   **** Warning: File encountered 'rangecheck' error while processing an image.
Loading NimbusSanL-ReguItal font from /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019023l.pfb... 4342240 2931231 2721360 1395616 3 done.

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** The file was produced by: 
   **** >>>> Prawn <<<<
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.
```

The image is then removed from the output PDF.

I've tried to recreate this by creating other PDFs with an embedded image using Prawn, but have not been able to reproduce.

Is there some way to get ghostscript to autocorrect or fix issues like these?

- https://s3.amazonaws.com/test-filestore/image.pdf
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/test-filestore/signature.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the current version of Ghostscript (9.07) which might do better. Failing that you could open a bug report (you will need to attach the PDF file so it can be investigated).

Comment: Hi KenS.  Thanks for responding.  I've tried this with 9.07 as well, same issue.  I've uploaded the image, and the file I created with Prawn.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is still happening in even ghostscript 9.14.  However, with other output devices (png16m, tiffg4, etc) this doesn't happen.  additionally, with pdfjoin this does not happen as well.  Anyway to get around this now?

Comment: I updated the bug which was supposedly fixed in 01/2014 - http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=694371  Thanks for your help ahead of time!

Comment: I think you are misreading the date, the bug was fixed on June 10th this year (2014).

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I got confused by the duplicate ticket.